# Do people really use the grammar “Past Perfect+Past Simple”?

Tags: tense, backshifting

Grammar books say when something happens before something else, we should use had+past particle in the sentence that happened at first and then say the second sentence in past tense. Do people use it in their speaking/writing or is it just a rule?

Comment: I had answer, but deleted it.

Comment: Yes, we really use write and speak such sentences.  Do you have a question about a specific sentence?

Comment: _When I had eaten my dinner I washed up the dishes_. If it wasn't something that people used it wouldn't be a rule!  Oh, and it's _past participle_ - you left out a syllable.

Comment: It is not necessary when "after" and "before" are used in the sentence.